# jquery .get return odd results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading in a text file using jquery $.get.  I have the following code.

```
console.log("before the get");
$.get("testfile.txt", function(data){
   console.log("in the get");
   console.log(data);
});
console.log("after the get");
```

In the console, I would expect to see

```
before the get
in the get
'...the data...'
after the get
```

Instead, I am getting

```
before the get
after the get
in the get
'...the data...'
```

Why am I getting the odd order?  Thank you.

Comment: `.get()` is asynchronous so it goes off to process while the rest of your script continues

Comment: face palm - thanks much j08691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not odd. That's normal because the get request is async. The other codes oafter get call won't wait for the completion of get and continues execution.

You have to print the console log message after completion of the get call.

```
console.log("before the get");
$.get("testfile.txt", function(data){
   console.log("in the get");
   console.log(data);
   console.log("after the get");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I prefer you to read this documentations:
**aysnc : false**

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

It will tell the request to turn off the asynchronous

I hope this will help

So, instead use **$.ajax()** than $.get()